Locker blocking file from comments?
I am wondering why Locker Service would block a library from load if on the library we have a comment with "import()" word?
The real code doesn't have as a comment, but as you can see below, even when we commented out the code, the Locker is considering as execution code and blocks the library.
Example:
(() => {
  // if (moduleObject === void 0) {
  //   error("lazy: Expected the result of a dynamic import() call. Instead received: %s\n\nYour code should look like: \n  const MyComponent = lazy(() => import('./MyComponent'))\n\nDid you accidentally put curly braces around the import?", moduleObject);
  // }

  console.log('test my app');
})();


In Locker Console, I get the error below:
Error: possible import expression rejected around line 7

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console
I am trying to load a bundle for react and react-dom. If I have Locker On, my bundle doesn't load. If I have the Lightning Web Security On which I believe disabled Locker, the bundle loads with no issue. Any thoughts?
I should cover both scenarios since that Is a managed package and I am not sure what is the configuration that the customer would set.
Code above, is coming from React > React Lazy, so I can't do anything about that. I am not using the import, neither the code is being transpile to have the import, but the message has import though.
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/326832a56d41b4462919f9efe69916712ca87a95/packages/react/src/ReactLazy.js#L99
Updated Oct 1: This happens because I was trying to compile a react in development mode, if I deploy in Prod mode that message doesn't go on production mode and the code compiles in SF. However my question still valid on why we are doing that if the code is not an executable.
